# PHP strange error: variable instantiated then used in empty while loop fails with 500 but no error

Tags: php, debugging

Just came across this and was tough to debug.  I have a program here where everything works in the staging environment.  We put it on a production server and it's throwing HTTP 500 errors.  Nothing coming to the screen even though error messages are on and nothing in the logs either, even with loglevel at debug

The failure is when the controller tries to initialize the model class in the controller's constructor.

Turns out this function was making things all hinky:

```
 public function save_rebuilt_list(  )
 {
      $id_list = $this->get_id_list(  );
      while( $id_list  )
      {
      }
 }
```

Now, this function is never called, never referenced, nothing.  It was something  I was going to use then decided not too and forgot to remove. So its just sitting there in the model.

$this->get_id_list( ) is valid and the function does not take any parameters.   Also note that I am able to see errors, like if I did $id_list / 0 it would show an error on screen.  And for the record, taking out the loop made the program run like a champ.

I mess around a little, and it seems that anytime I create a function with a variable assignment and an empty while loop on that variable assignment, the application will 500 without any messages.

anyone ever hear of this or know WTF is going on?!

It's PHP 5.5.9 on apache2.

Comment: When you get a 500 error, you need to check the error log on the server, the errors don't go to the client.

Comment: Yes I know I was working on the server.